# How can I copy spreadsheet from one xlsm file to another xlsm file in spreadsheet2 in c#.net

Tags: c#, xls

I have a xlsm template. using that i was able to create a new spreadsheet(sheet1). How can I copy he xlsm template to another spreadsheet(s
heet2). So that I will be having sheet1 and sheet2 in a single xlsm file

Answer (score 0):

public virtual void Copy (

```
[OptionalAttribute] Object Before,
[OptionalAttribute] Object After
```

)

Using the InnerObject property of the worksheet, you can add

Copy before sheet1 as:

currentsheet.Copy(Globals.Sheet1.InnerObject, missing);

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.copy(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If the OP is trying to copy a sheet from one workbook to another, which it sounds like, though it isn't entirely clear, this won't work.